# IndexError: index 140 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 140

Tags: python, numpy

Hi am trying to open the image with and reshape it and i get that erorr can someone help me plz

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 


file_handle=open("compressed_image2.bin","rb")
img_compressed=np.fromfile(file_handle,dtype='uint8')
file_handle.close()


def decodeImage(img):
     original = np.zeros(img_compressed[0]*img_compressed[1],dtype = "uint8")

     t = y = count = 0
     for i in range(len(img)):
        if not (i == 0 or i == 1):
           if (t % 2) == 0:
              count = img[i]
           else:
              for x in range(count):
                  original[y+x] = img[i]
              y += count
        t += 1
     return original  
 
original=decodeImage(img_compressed)
        
C = len(original)/len(img_compressed)
R = 1 - 1/C
print("\n Die Kompressionsrate ist C=",C)
print("\n Die Redundanz ist R = ",R)
original = np.reshape(original, [img_compressed[1], img_compressed[0]])
plt.imshow(original, cmap = "gray")
```

and that is my erorr can someone see where is the problem?

```
, line 27, in decodeImage
    original[y+x] = img[i]

IndexError: index 140 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 140
```

Comment: in python, an index starts at zero and goes to `N-1`

Comment: Typo.  You want `original = np.zeros(img_compressed.shape[0]*img_compressed.shape[1],dtype = "uint8")`.  You're using the first two pixel values, not the width and height.  You have the same problem in the `np.reshape` line.

Comment: Well, hang on; my advice is not good, either.  You're not reading it as an image, you're reading it as a byte stream. Where did the file come from?  It looks like you're trying to do RLE compression, but who wrote it?  If this is a 2D array, then the first two bytes won't have width and height.  You need to show us the first few bytes of the file, or at least the spec you used to write this.

Comment: thanks 
i did it with shape[0] and shape[1] 
i had anoter problem      IndexError: tuple index out of range
it is an image